# How to use Collapsing Toolbar with TabLayout using Material and AndroidX components?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, androidx

I'm trying to use both Toolbar and TabLayout with CollapsingToolbarLayout but I'm getting a very strange behavior with the tab layout. The idea is to have the TabLayout with a transparent background when the Toolbar is expanded, and when collapsed, to be under the Toolbar like any other Activity with both Toolbar and TabLayout.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
      android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
      app:contentScrim="@color/primary"
      app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsingToolbarExpandedTitleTheme">

      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

      <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTitleTheme"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

      <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

      </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

  </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

  <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
      android:id="@+id/view_pager"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

  </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]
[image]

UPDATE: Following the example mentioned by @ ismail alaoui (https://android.jlelse.eu/parallax-scrolling-header-tabs-android-tutorial-2cc6e40aa257), the layout better, but the TabLayout is still WHITE. There's no Style associated with it.

[image]
[image]

UPDATE: Adding android:background="transparent" to the TabLayout, as @ismail suggested, solves this issue. I also added an style to the TabLayout (Widget.MaterialComponents.TabLayout.Colored) just to improve the layout.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i suggest you to follow [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/parallax-scrolling-header-tabs-android-tutorial-2cc6e40aa257) tutorial , it explain how to do what you are exactly looking for , it's not using androidx component , but you can use it the same way  , enjoy !

**edit** **:**

add this to `appBarLayout` and `TabLayout` attribute :

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: I did it now and the layout is better, but the TabLayout continues white.

Comment: check your tablayout style

Comment: there's no style associated with the TabLayout. Its exactly as the example.

Comment: Yes, I'm updating the question.

Comment: Add this to appbarlayout android:background="@android:color/transparent">

Comment: Adding this don't change nothing. =(

Comment: Please also add it to your tablayout attribute

Comment: Thanks ismail, it works!! Feel free to improve you answer to add this detail. I will update the question. Many thanks!!!

Comment: done ! you are welcome , please don't forget to consider my answer :)